# how to fix html page automatically margins my body?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a school project to build a website. I'm trying to make the navbar and the header background different colors but it doesn't seem to reach the end of the page. I attached a screenshot where you can see that my headers background color(white and gray) didn't reach the end and you can still see the blue background. attaching my code aswell:

```
<body>
    <div class="Headers">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            COMPUTER GAMES REVIEW BY ASAF DAMTI
        </h1>
        <h2 id="secondheader">
            Welcome to my site
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="Menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Details</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">On Me</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Links</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive/" target="_blank">Csgo</a>
                        <a href="https://www.roblox.com/home" target="_blank">Roblox</a>
                        <a href="https://www.minecraft.net/en-us" target="_blank">Minecraft</a>
                        <a href="https://playvalorant.com/en-us/" target="_blank">Valorant</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Contact me</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the html
css is:

```
body {
    background-color: darkcyan;
    font-family: Calibri;
}

.Headers{
    background-color:white;
}
#secondheader{
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    opacity:50%;
}
.Menu{
    background-color:gray;
}
.Menu a{
    background-color:gray;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:4px;
    padding-right:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
.Menu a:visited{
    color:black;
}
.Menu a:hover{
    background-color:white;
}
.Menu ul{
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
}
.Menu li{
    display:inline;
    padding:5px;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: gray;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
   
}
.dropdown-content{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    min-width:160px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.dropdown-content a{
        color: black;
        padding: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
}
```

[Picture of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaCjY.png)

Answer (score 0):

In most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides.

So it is needed to override that margin CSS attribute to remove the space on the header.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also `h1` tag has got default `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` so you need to override that styles too.

```
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-top: 0;">
  COMPUTER GAMES REVIEW BY ASAF DAMTI
</h1>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  font-family: Calibri;
  margin: 0;
}

.Headers {
  background-color: white;
}

#secondheader {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  opacity: 50%;
}

.Menu {
  background-color: gray;
}

.Menu a {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.Menu a:visited {
  color: black;
}

.Menu a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.Menu ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.Menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Headers">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-top: 0;">
      COMPUTER GAMES REVIEW BY ASAF DAMTI
    </h1>
    <h2 id="secondheader">
      Welcome to my site
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="Menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Details</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">On Me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Links</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive/" target="_blank">Csgo</a>
            <a href="https://www.roblox.com/home" target="_blank">Roblox</a>
            <a href="https://www.minecraft.net/en-us" target="_blank">Minecraft</a>
            <a href="https://playvalorant.com/en-us/" target="_blank">Valorant</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It worked but only on the sides the top hasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this to your style:

```css
*
{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}
```

If you have any more questions, be sure to ask!
Have a great day :)